# problems connecting data access layer to wcf data service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question but the error I am getting is in the data access layer of an app that is trying to access the api of a web service. The error that I am receiving is an `InvalidOperatioException` was handled by user code.

This error happens when I attempt to load a page that should load a grid view of user characters. The code in the DAL where the error is is below.

```
Public Function SelectAllCharactersByUserId(userId As Integer) As List(Of CharacterDto) Implements ICharacterDao.SelectCharactersByUserId
    Dim characterDtos As New List(Of CharacterDto)
    Using wcf As New PyritegoldWCF.ServiceClient()
        For Each wfcCharacter In wcf.SelectCharactersByUserId(userId)
            characterDtos.Add(FromWcfCharacter(wfcCharacter))
        Next
    End Using
    Return characterDtos
End Function
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message?

Comment: This?

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'PyritegoldWCF.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'PyritegoldWCF.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

The exception is implying that your app.config is missing some configuration, you should have a section in your app config which looks like the example shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx).